# Request to save on close

Tags: c#, forms, file-io, save

I am wanting my program to request a user to save their files if they have been edited before they exit. The code i am posting i do know does not work but in a general idea of what i want to happen:

```
if (richTextBox1.TextChanged = true)
        {
            SaveFileDialog op = new SaveFileDialog();
            op.Title = "Save";
            op.Filter = "Text Documents(*.txt)|*.txt|All Files(*.*)|*.*";
            if (op.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                richTextBox1.SaveFile(op.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
                this.Text = op.FileName;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a handler for the `OnClosing` event of the form. There you can ask the typical "Yes, no cancel" question. Do not confuse this with the `OnClosed` event.